# What is the Out-of-time-ordered correlator for free fermion system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, chaos-theory

The Out-of-time-ordered correlator (OTOC) is defined as $\langle[W(t),V(0)]^2\rangle$, and can be considered as a new way to extract quantum chaos. However, the understanding of this special correlator is not clear. For a simple example, what the free fermion OTOC behaves? Both lattice or continuum case are welcome.

Comment: Since OTOC can detect the scarmbling of quantum dynamics system, the interest lies in quantum many-body interacting systems to reveal its  quantum chaotic behaviour (some works on interacting fermion system, e.g. https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.95.011601, and for those work with SKY model you can find them easily) . For free fermion, this correlator will simply trivial and free of Lyapunov  exponent (chaos doesn't occur in such integrable/dynamic determined system) and stay constant, which depends on what local obserables you choose and calculate with fermion commutator.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, your definition of the OTOC is wrong. It is supposed to be composed of the static and time-evolved versions of the same operator, so it should read $C(t) = - \langle [\hat{V}(t),\hat{V}(0)]^2 \rangle$. The minus sign has become standard in the field.

The understanding of this function is not that hard to grasp: if $\hat{V}(t)$ and $\hat{V}(0)$ commute for all times, nothing happens. Your question, regarding the free fermion case, can be generalised for all cases where $\hat{V}$ commutes with the Hamiltonian: nothing happens. This makes sense, since if you're looking for something that could be called *chaos*, then it shouldn't arise with such a trivial time evolution. But if your time evolution is interesting enough to provide operators that stop commuting, then your OTOC starts giving off meaningful stuff. [It was postulated](http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_028_06_1200.pdf) that a special (momentum) OTOC version growth rate should be closely tied with Lyapunov exponents, [something that didn't turn out to be exactly true](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.086801), but close enough in some aspects. The reason behind this postulate regarding the momentum-OTOC is that, using a test function $f$ and the static position basis,

\begin{align}
[\hat{p}(t), \hat{p}(0) ]f  &= -i \hbar \left[ \hat{p}(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial q(0)} - \frac{\partial}{\partial q(0)}(\hat{p}(t) f) \right] \\
&= (i \hbar f) \frac{\partial \hat{p}(t)}{\partial q(0)} \, ,
\end{align}

so that

\begin{align}
C(t) &= -\langle [\hat{p}(t), \hat{p}(0) ]^2 \rangle \\
&= \hbar^2 \bigg\langle \left( \frac{\partial \hat{p}(t)}{\partial q(0)} \right)^2 \bigg\rangle \\
&\approx \bigg\langle \left( \frac{\Delta{p}(t)}{\Delta q(0)} \right)^2 \bigg\rangle_{\text{phase space}} \quad (\equiv C_{cl}(t))\, ,
\end{align}

that is, for times smaller than Ehrenfest's time, this approximation should be quite reasonable. Now, if we're talking about a chaotic map, it means that for small deviations on position we'll have very large (exponential) deviations on momentum. This suggests that, after a little analysis,

\begin{align}
C_{cl} (t) &\approx (e^{ \Lambda t})^2 \\
\Rightarrow \Lambda &= \lim_{t \to \infty} \lim_{\Delta q(0) \to 0} \frac{1}{2t} \ln \left[ \frac{C_{cl}(t+1)}{C_{cl}(1)} \right] \, .
\end{align}

The classical expression for the Lyapunov exponent is given by

\begin{align}
\lambda = \lim_{t \to \infty} \lim_{\delta Z(0) \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \ln \left( \frac{|\delta Z(t)|}{|\delta Z(0)|} \right) \, ,
\end{align}

where $\delta Z$ represents the separation between trajectories and $|.|$ the norm. Notice how $\Lambda$ and $\lambda$ are very similar. This motivates the study of OTOCs in the context of quantum chaos.

Comment: First thank you for answering. However I don't think the minus sign is by any means conventional or standard. For a very recent paper Phys. Rev. Lett. 120, 110603 (2018), the equation (1) is clearly without minus sign. I can see some of researchers might be more comfortable with a minus sign, such as in Phys. Rev. Lett. 118, 086801 (2017), but it's not normal.

Comment: And I actually have a question. Is that the OTOC of a state would be interesting only with some sophisticated choice of operators? And even if I choose two sets of operators that have some non-trivial property, the two corresponding OTOC could behave differently?

Comment: I am used to the definition with the minus sign and didn't know people used it with a plus sign too. Now, what do you mean by sophisticated operators? My example is nothing but two momenta... Quite peasant.

Comment: Dear @QuantumBrick, could you please introduce some introductory materials (books or papers) for me on OTOC, I am recently starting to learn this but have no clue where to start, thanks a lot.